# Citation for trace of inverse matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, reference-request, trace, positive-definite

I am looking for a source for the following "well known" inequality that I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201330). The corresponding matrix properties/assumtions are also mentioned there in more detail.

$$ \mbox{Tr} \left( A^{-1} \right) \ge n^2 \, \mbox{Tr}(A)^{-1} $$

Can someone point me to a paper or book to which I can cite this inequality in my thesis? I looked up several known linear algebra books, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: It seems that your inequality is a special case of Theorem 2.1 of [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/280FA236429711AAD68992AE583D82D4/S0004972712000627a.pdf/trace-inequalities-for-matrices.pdf), so you may cite this one.

Comment: VanBaffo suggested a linked question, which had been linked by the OP herself. It contains enough information to construct the proof. However, the present question requests a _reference_ to use in a thesis, not a proof.

Comment: @SeewooLee Thm 2.1 and further theorems in this paper are only for positive exponents, right? In addition, I don't think that the inverse of a matrix can be dealt with as a "simple exponeniation".

Comment: This is just a rearrangement of $\|A^{-1/2}\|_F^2\|A^{1/2}\|_F^2\ge\langle A^{-1/2},A^{1/2}\rangle_F^2$, which is essentially Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I don't think you need any citation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference to a general version of this inequality (inverse log-convex property). It can be found [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/65A19F90EC9C5C3DA1B8391FAF09D73C/S001309150001021Xa.pdf/inequalities_concerning_the_inverses_of_positive_definite_matrices.pdf). This specific case uses $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=0$ which leads to this simplified form of the inequality.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I edited into a better format.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you're aware, you need more assumptions for this inequality to be true. Let $A$ be a diagonal matrix with values $-1, -1/2$ on the diagonal.

Then
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(A^{-1})  = -3 < -8/3 = 2^2 \mathrm{Tr}(A)^{-1}.
$$

For $A$ with positive eigenvalues, the inequality is true and can be seen as a simple consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The assumptions can be found in more detail in the link that I provided to the original post to which I was referring to. But you are right, I probably should mention the matrix properties again in my own post/question. @DrewBrady And thanks for the hint regarding Cauchy-Schwarz, I didn't see that connection and I will look further into it.